# How do I create a difference in means table with a column for N observations using esttab?

Tags: stata

I'm trying to create a table showing the difference in means of two groups but I'm struggling to get exactly the right columns. I'm specifically trying to recreate a table that includes a column indicating N. I'm really confused how I would go about doing this. Here's the code for the bulk of the kind of table I'm talking about:

```
sysuse auto, clear

eststo all: quietly estpost summarize ///
    price mpg weight headroom trunk
eststo domestic: quietly estpost summarize ///
    price mpg weight headroom trunk if foreign == 0
eststo foreign: quietly estpost summarize ///
    price mpg weight headroom trunk if foreign == 1
eststo diff: quietly estpost ttest ///
    price mpg weight headroom trunk, by(foreign) unequal

esttab all domestic foreign diff, ///
cells("mean(pattern(1 1 1 0) fmt(2)) b(star pattern(0 0 0 1) fmt(2))" "sd(pattern(1 1 1 0) par fmt(2)) t(pattern(0 0 0 1) par fmt(2))") ///
label
```

In this scenario, I want a column N that just lists 74 in each row. In this shortened example, it doesn't make much sense but I'm using multiple data sources with the same variables and I want to stack the difference in means tables together.[image: output]

Comment: The difficulty is that your example doesn't seem to be an example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the number of observations in each subsample (in this case `by(foreign)`) using `N_1` and `N_2` as follows:

```
 sysuse auto, clear

estpost ttest price mpg weight headroom trunk, by(foreign)

esttab . , ///
cell(( N_2(fmt(%12.0fc)) mu_2(fmt(%12.3fc)) ///
       N_1(fmt(%12.0fc)) mu_1(fmt(%12.3fc)) ///
       b(fmt(%12.3fc)) t(fmt(%12.2fc)) )) ///
noobs label collabels(Count Mean Count Mean Diff T-Stat )
```